# Microsoft Access Query - Want Sum([Sold Products]) = 0 when non existent i table

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a table which contains 4 fields.
This is all focused on Inventory.

**Channel**
Where was the sale made (Webshop, Groupon, Store, etc)

**Date**
When was the sale made

**Part SKU**
What product was sold

**Stock Change**
How much was sold

Now, the end goal here is to create a Pivot Table in Excel that shows how the inventory changes over time.
I have concluded that in order for me to do this, I need the datasource (A query of this table) to contain entries for all products on all dates.
Problem is, there is no sales on weekends and most products are not sold every day.

I've looked a lot and found *Left join* examples and people talking about creating calendar tables. However, I have been working on this for hours and I'm still not sure where to start.

I came to the right answer, it is posted down there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% positive you actually need the data in this format for an Excel pivot table.  But, it is still an interesting question.

The solution has two parts:  the first is generating the rows.  The second is bringing in the additional data.  The first is solved with a cross join ("," in MS Access, ARRGGG).  The second through a `LEFT JOIN`.  Something like this:

```
select s.sku, d.date, nz(i.inventorychange, 0) as inventorychange
from ((select distinct sku from inventory) as s,
      (select distinct date from inventory) as d
     ) left join
     inventory as i
     on i.sku = s.sku and i.date as d.date;
```

Note:  this only includes the `sku`s and `date`s that are in the table (anywhere).  If there are other dates, then you need a calendar table (or something similar) as a source for the `d` subquery.

EDIT:

I thought the above would work in MS Access.  Perhaps this version will work:

```
select sd.sku, sd.date, nz(i.inventorychange, 0) as inventorychange
from (select sku, date
      from (select distinct sku from inventory) as s,
           (select distinct date from inventory) as d
     ) sd left join
     inventory as i
     on i.sku = sd.sku and i.date as sd.date;
```

Comment: Ok maybe I should have explained my entire idea instead of just my supposed next step.

The data I have is how much goes out of the inventory and I have how much goes in. I put this in the same table, sales give negative values and refills give positive values. Hence the field name "Inventory Change"

What I want in the end is a Pivot table in Excel that shows the Inventory level of each product for the last 14 days as well as the sum of all changes. The source needs these values for all dates, otherwise the Levels only show on dates where there was a change while the rest show as 0.

Comment: I tried your solution but I get "Syntax Error in JOIN operation."

Answer (score 0):

If i am not mistaken ...notice the last part of the join

```
s.[Part SKU], d.Date, nz(i.[Stock Change], 0) as [Stock Change]
from ((select distinct [Part SKU] from [Product Parts Changes]) as s,
  (select distinct Date from Calendar) as d
 ) left join [Product Parts Changes] as i on i.[Part SKU] = s.[Part SKU] AND
 i.Date = d.Date;
```

Comment: Thank you John, You are correct, there was a mistake there. However it still throws the same Syntax Error in JOIN operation after being corrected.

Comment: Are you sure that you are joining Fields with the same DataType ?

Comment: That query just isn't the solution and it's not correct syntax. Updated original post...

Answer (score 0):

You will need a list of dates.

Create a table with integer numbers and then this query:

```
SELECT DateAdd("d", -[Number], Date()) AS [Date]
FROM tblNumbers
WHERE tblNumbers.Number Between 14 And 1
ORDER BY tblNumbers.Number Desc;
```

This will give you the last 14 days. Use this as source in a new query where you create an outer join to your inventory table where you group and sum your data.

For having a row for each date and product, you'll need a Cartesian (multiplying) query along:

```
SELECT 
    DateAdd("d", -[Number], Date()) AS [Date], 
    ProductID
FROM 
    tblNumbers,
    tblProducts
WHERE 
    tblNumbers.Number Between 14 And 1
ORDER BY 
    tblNumbers.Number Desc,
    tblProducts.ProductID;
```

Comment: So now I have Rows for dates with no other data.
What I want is one row for each product AND date that contains no data.

Comment: I expanded the query to cover this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer. I finally found it.

```
SELECT Nz([Product Parts Changes].[Trello Board Name],"No Trello Board") AS [Trello Board Name], [All SKU Calendar].Date, [All SKU Calendar].[Part SKU], nz([Product Parts Changes].[Stock Change],0) As [Stock Change]
FROM [All SKU Calendar] LEFT JOIN [Product Parts Changes] ON ([All SKU Calendar].[Part SKU] = [Product Parts Changes].[Part SKU]) AND ([All SKU Calendar].Date = [Product Parts Changes].Date)
GROUP BY [All SKU Calendar].Date, [All SKU Calendar].[Part SKU], [Product Parts Changes].[Stock Change], [Product Parts Changes].[Trello Board Name]
HAVING ((([All SKU Calendar].Date) Between (SELECT DISTINCT MIN([Product Parts Changes].Date) FROM [Product Parts Changes]) And (SELECT DISTINCT MAX([Product Parts Changes].Date) FROM [Product Parts Changes])))
ORDER BY [All SKU Calendar].Date;
```

Note that I added the Query ALL SKU Calendar, the result of this query is a list of all dates and product SKUs.